# PR2 Fuerte repository

Tags: ros-fuerte, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like some of the repository links to PR2 code are pointing to old versions. For example, [pr2_mechanism_controllers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism_controllers) are pointing to SVN with a version different from the one which is described in API section for Fuerte (compare function `publishTransform()` from [SVN](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_controllers/branches/pr2_controllers-1.4/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/pr2_odometry.cpp) and [API Reference](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/pr2_mechanism_controllers/html/classcontroller_1_1Pr2Odometry.html#a7195f26a6078cf7849cd025308431871))

This gives a lot of problems when compiling from source, especially when code is pulled by `roslocate` as it returns wrong addresses for stacks.

So, there are two questions:

1. Where can I find the right PR2 code for Fuerte? (e.g. `pr2_mechanism_controllers`)
2. Where should I report such problems in future?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43676/pr2-fuerte-repository/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The latest version is available in trunk: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_controllers/trunk/

I suggest pulling down the entire stack rather than individual packages.

If you're on Ubuntu, you can install the `ros-fuerte-pr2-controllers` deb package instead.

Future meta-issues like this should probably be reported on the pr2-users mailing list: http://lists.willowgarage.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/pr2-users

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-12**:
Thanks. I used roslocate which pulled entire stack, but of a wrong version. I am on Fedora, so have to build everything from sources.